# How to end JQuery endless scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I know this topic is overflowing on this site however when using the endless scroll plugin below I was hoping to figure out a way of just loading from my ajax request but somehow just ending at some point. e.g. eventually reaching the bottom? Any help is much appreciated?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{
    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
    $.ajax({
    url: "{{url('contentpage')}}",
    success: function(html)
    {
        if(html)
        {
            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
        }else
        {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
        }
    }
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you could end it, it wouldn't be *endless* !

Comment: I know! but are you saying im better off using an alternative plugin or can I change this by adding some kind of loop for it to only append a certain number of times?

Comment: If you use `on()` to bind the scroll event, you could at some point just use `off()` to unbind it

Comment: could you please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var cp = 1;
var pagestotal = $("div.page-nav").find("a.pag:last").text();

function() {  // Optional callback when new content is successfully loaded

        cp++;

        if(cp == pagestotal) {

            $(window).unbind('.infscr');

        } else {}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an idea as to how I would implement this into the code above?

Answer (score 0):

How about when there's no content to show then set a flag to false.

So to do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var postToShowFlag = true;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (postToShowFlag) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
          $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('contentpage')}}",
            success: function(html) {
              if (html) {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
              } else {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                postToShowFlag = false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving Infinite Scrolling behaviour you just need `Pure Css OR Css & Javascript` (it depends on the Browser support and your audience)

but... DON'T use `onScroll`: you can do all that just with `Vanilla Javascript` and the `IntersectionObserver API`.

All you need to do is place elements and listen for when they become available in the screen. The `IntersectionObserver API` is very customisable to fit all your needs.

In summary: you accomplish that with a few javascript & html lines and it's much more performant than listening for scroll events in the browsers

I recently put together an article about infinite scrolling [check it out here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/infinite-scroll-done-the-right-way-33cb7be18407)

I hope it does server you as a guidance to your specific needs